# How can I make a prepared statement with an unknown number of parameters? (for a search box)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this foreach loop, that I use for a search feature:

```
$keywords=$_GET['keyword']; 
$exploded=explode(' ',trim($keywords));
$mysql_command="SELECT * FROM items WHERE completed='1' AND ";

foreach ($exploded as $key => $value){
    if ($key>0)
        $mysql_command.=' OR ';

    $mysql_command.="title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?";
        }
```

I want to use this prepared statement:

```
$stmt=$cxn->prepare($mysql_command);
$stmt->execute(array("%$value%","%$value%"));
```

The problem is, I don't know how many keywords there is going to be. So how can I make a prepared statement with an unknown number of keywords?

Thanks a lot in advance. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you don't create the array after the request like this :

```
$params=Array();
foreach($exploded as $key => $value){
  $params[]="%$value%";
}
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: Please help me understand how this works.  The documentation states that for object oriented style, `bool mysqli_stmt::execute ( void )`; meaning you can't pass a parameter to `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli does not allow to call `execute` or `bind_param` with an array directly. You have to use `call_user_func_array` with that, like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array("s", "%test%"));
```

Then, to build the array, you can use this:

```
class BindParam{
    private $v = array("");

    public function add( $type, &$value ){
        $this->v[0] .= $type;
        $this->v[] = &$value;
    }

    public function get(){
        return $this->v;
    }
}
```

Which is a tweaked version of this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#109256. Then use it like this:

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $filter);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "title LIKE ?";
        $a = '%'.$term.'%';
        $bindParam->add('s', $a); // can't pass by value
    }
}
$filter_sql = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits);

/*...*/

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $bindParam->get());
```